# How to reload document by resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why this code doesn't work:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    document.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: i wish we had a `no worky!` tag (http://www.dilbert.com/strips/comic/2010-03-17/)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Sounds like bad user interface design to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$(window).bind('resize',function(){
     window.location.href = window.location.href;
});
```

Reference: 
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/anyone-know-how-to-refresh-reload-page-on-browser-resize

Answer (score 0):

The `resize` event fires many times (depending on the browser) as you resize...there's probably a *much* better way to solve your problem (at least, I can't imagine that constantly reloading the page would be an optimal solution...).

For example if you're doing this to get your `$(document).ready()` code to run again?  In that case for example you can use a named function.  For example:

```
function myFunc() {
  //do stuff
}

$(myFunc);                 //run on DOM ready
$(window).resize(myFunc);  //run when resizing
```