# VBScript in HTML (Inline): How to refresh and quit

Tags: html, vbscript, refresh

I'm making a simple VBscript program within HTML to receive a word and check if it's a Palindrome.

I have the code set-up except one thing - In the end, if a user enters a word which is NOT a palindrome, I have a msgbox which has a vbYesNO, and it says, "Sorry, not a palindrome! Do you wish to retry?".

I want the script to refresh the page if the user clicks Yes, and to close the current tab/stop the script if the user clicks No.
I am writing all of this on Notepad, and saving it as .html. I can also only execute this script on IE.

I am posting my code here.

```html
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10"></head>

<body bgcolor="cyan">
<p style="color:#0F104E;text-align:center;font-size:75px">A game of Palindromes!</p>
<script language="vbscript">

option explicit
DIM a,b,c,d,x,y,z

a=MsgBox("Do you know what a Palindrome is?", vbYesNo)
Select case a
    case vbNo
        msgbox("A palindrome is a word which is the same spelled forwards or backwards, e.g: Eye.")
End select

document.write("<h1>Palindromes found:</h1>")
b=msgbox("Let's play a game about Palindromes!", vbOKonly)

Do while z=0
    x=Ucase(inputbox("Enter a word to check if it's a Palindrome:(Not case-sensitive!)"))
    If x<>"" then
         y=strReverse(x)
         z=strComp(x,y)
         If z=0 then
             Msgbox("It's a palindrome! Let's see how many you know!")
             document.write("<h2><ul><li>" & x & "</li></ul></h2>")
          end if
    else 
        Quit
    end if
LOOP 

c=msgbox("Sorry! Not a palindrome. Try again?", vbYesNo)
select case c
    case vbNo
        msgbox("Thanks for playing!")
    'I want it to close the tab
    case vbYes
    'I want this to refresh the page or loop back to the beginning
end select

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use javascript/jquery

Comment: @21Canadians [Really?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/158100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although VBScript is still supported in internet explorer if you start working on new projects you better look into [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) because that is supported across many browsers, including browsers from Microsoft.

You're code only needed one fix and two statements. I first show the changed code and will explain what I've added:

```
option explicit
DIM a,b,c,d,x,y,z

a=MsgBox("Do you know what a Palindrome is?", vbYesNo)
Select case a
    case vbNo
        msgbox("A palindrome is a word which is the same spelled forwards or backwards, e.g: Eye.")
End select

document.write("<h1>Palindromes found:</h1>")
b=msgbox("Let's play a game about Palindromes!", vbOKonly)

Do while z=0
    x=Ucase(inputbox("Enter a word to check if it's a Palindrome:(Not case-sensitive!)"))
    If x<>"" then
         y=strReverse(x)
         z=strComp(x,y)
         If z=0 then
             Msgbox("It's a palindrome! Let's see how many you know!")
             document.write("<h2><ul><li>" & x & "</li></ul></h2>")
          end if
    else 
        'instead of quit use Exit Do 
        Exit Do
    end if
Loop

c=msgbox("Sorry! Not a palindrome. Try again?", vbYesNo)
select case c
    case vbNo
        msgbox("Thanks for playing!")
       'I want it to close the tab
       window.close()
    case vbYes
       'I want this to refresh the page or loop back to the beginning
       window.location.href = window.location.href
end select
```

First the keyword `Quit` you used is not allowed in a browser. Instead of that I simply exited from the Do While loop with the [`Exit Do`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57ykwk20(v=vs.84).aspx) statement.

To close the window (or tab) I used a method that is available on the [`window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535873(v=vs.85).aspx) object called [`close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536367(v=vs.85).aspx).

To reload the current page I used the earlier mentioned window object and it's object `location` to set the `href` property to itself. A trick that is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4460244/578411) by user [raRaRa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388073/rarara)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm currently in school and we just learnt a bit of VBscript hence I only know that. Hopefully next year we'll learn JS :D

When I was researching to find a command to make the tab close, I found a "Wscript.Quit" command, however, it didn't work with IE. 
So is there a list of commands for browsers which I can access online for future reference?

Thanks again.